# How to mix few jQuery UI range slider together?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider, range, mixed

Anyone know how to mix few jQuery UI range draggable slider together?

Sample Image that showing what I mean: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cpo0.png)

Sample code for single range draggable slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 71,
            max: 109,
            values: [75, 100],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#size-range").html(Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[0] % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[1] % 12) + '"');
                $("#min_inches").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#max_inches").val(ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        $("#size-range").html(Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) % 12) + '"');
        $("#min_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
        $("#max_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
    });
    </script>

    <p>Size Range: <strong><span id="size-range"></span></strong> <small><em>(drag slider handles below to specify)</em></small></p>

    <div id="slider-range"></div>

    <input type="text" name="min_inches" id="min_inches" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="max_inches" id="max_inches" value="" />
```

..please help me.

Comment: If I want handle1 cannot drag to same with handle2 I mean like if handle1 is '18' then handle2 cannot drag to '18' only can drag until '19', how can i make it? Anyone please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this solution: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/ui-slider/slider_test.html

Comment: An answer containing just a link is not a good answer, as the linked page can change or vanish, as this one has. You should have summarised the answer here; now this information is lost to the ether.